# PrimeNg - Enable to select the future date from next month that is visible on the current month displayed

Tags: angular, user-interface, primeng

I am using Prime Ng Calendar and I want to enable or allow select future date from next month that is visible on current month which shows in the highlight of my screenshot

[image]

Able to select future date that is visible in current month displayed

Answer (score 2):

I fix it by adding this on the p-calendar

> [selectOtherMonths]="true"

If returns UI error just declare a variable and make it boolean then bind it .

> [selectOtherMonths]="selectOtherMonths"